# Excel 2016: IF function using position of cell relative to another cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm trying to use IF to return a value that depends on the position of one cell relative to another in the same column.

[Spreadsheet Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wGeF.png)

If you click the above image, you'll see a number of columns with the possible values of "No," "Yes," "Yes>No," and "No>Yes."

The equation will go in the "Category of Change," row, one equation for each column. If the "Yes>No," is lower in the column than the "No>Yes," I want to return "Less Frequently," and if the opposite is true, I want to return "More Frequently" ("Same," if there is no "Yes>No," or "No>Yes").

I've tried using ARRAY and INDEX functions, but I'm not sure how to get Excel to "look" for each of those values, and then compare their ranking in the column.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What if there is only `Yes>No` or `No>Yes`?

Comment: Good question--There can only be one pair of "Yes>No," and "No>Yes," or just all "No," or "Yes," which would produce "Same."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATCH will return the relative row number.  This assumes the first column of data is in E2:E8.

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH("Yes>No",E2:E8,0)>MATCH("No>Yes",E2:E8,0),"Less Frequently","More Frequently"),"Same")
```

It is looking for exact matches, so if you have typos, it will always default to `Same`.  If only one is found then it will still produce `Same`

You would put int he first cell and copy/drag over, the references will change automatically.